# Change AutoLayout Constraints during Run Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

How is it possible to change AutoLayout Constraints during run time.

I need to change the coordinate of view during run time so i did following:

```
 if ([OfferText length] != 0) {
            cell.topContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake( 71, 4, [Util window_width]-71,50);
            cell.topContentView.frame = newFrame;
        }
```

While doing that I get following warning. Is it possible to change the auto layout constraints during run time.

```
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fca729606a0 UIView:0x7fca7296c6e0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fca729712b0.topMargin + 2>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fca7286f620 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fca7296c6e0.midY == + 29>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fca7286f670 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fca7296c6e0(50)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fca705c9770 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fca729712b0]   (Names: '|':CollectionBrandCell:0x7fca72968820 )>"
)
```

I find my solution using following code:

**in .h**  of tableviewcell In my case

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintsTopContentView;
```

and **in .m**

```
if ([OfferText length] != 0) {
            cell.constraintsTopContentView.constant=-4;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are setting up constraints from Storyboard, then make the outlet's of the constraints that are required to change the view's co-ordinates.
For Example:
If you want to change the top space of some view XYZ, then please do the following:

1. Select that view's top constraint and make outlet in .h file. This will
   look like this.

   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *XYZ'stopConstraint;
2. Now, change this constraints constant, when you required by the following 
   code.

   self.XYZ'stopConstraints.constant = youValue;

Also, please remove this line from your code as it is not necessary as per my view.

```
 cell.topContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Comment: also please accept the answer so that if anyone is having a problem similar to this, they can easily get the solution and you're welcome bro..!! Cheers..!!

Answer (score 0):

Create outlets for constraints you want to change (similar to UI controls); then change `constant` property of them.
Your warning caused because you use `cell.topContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;`. This will creates some new constraints (`NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`) and cause conflict with olds.

Comment: how can i do that can u post some screen shots or give me some ideas

Comment: Auto layout is really magically. You can find some useful things at here: http://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/. Hope this help u!

Comment: [ cell.lblRemarks sizeToFit];
 doesn't work out until and unless i use     cell.lblRemarks.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
Do u have any ideas ab this problem

Comment: Labels can auto resize depend of text you set for them.

Comment: Ex: if you add constraints for cell.lblRemarks with top, left and right; then when runtime, Auto Layout will auto calculate height for cell.lblRemarks depend current text of it (That is Intrinsic Content Size). If your label is multiline, remember set numberOfLines = 0. In Auto Layout, sizeToFit seem to be not suitable.